# get events of new added calender in outlook from Graph API

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get events of the newly added calendar from the directory in Outlook from Graph API (add_calendar.jpg). In graph API docs,

I tried

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/calendar/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Buser-id%7D/calendar/events)

it is giving me events, but not all, only a few events (10 results)

is it any api permission issue or by default limit in API result in graph explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint returns 10 items by default. When there is a more than 10 items available then the response contains `@odata.nextLink` with the link to the next page with next 10 items.

You can change the page size in `$top` query parameter. I think that max value is 999.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/calendar/events?$top=50
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$top=50
```